# Returning a non NULL string causes compilation error

Tags: c

I'm trying to do something very simple in C, which is to process and return a char, and have that function's return value be a 'usable' char in another function.

```
char name_the_file(char *fileName) {
    if (fileName == NULL) {
        fileName = "myFile";
    }
    globalFile = fileName;
    return fileName;
}

FILE *load_File(char *fileName) {
    fileName = name_the_file(fileName);
    FILE *filePointer;
    filePointer = open_file(fileName);
    return fopen(fileName, "r");
}
```

I keep getting the diagnostic: `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]` and I don't understand what is wrong with what I am doing. I can't redefine `fileName`?

Comment: char * needed and you have char for the function definition.

Comment: You are returning the passed pointer as char.

Comment: There is also `globalFile` undeclared...

Comment: @joaumg it is defined! sorry, this is only a snippet :-)

Comment: @RichardChambers thank you! I didn't realize functions could be defined that way, I'm only just learning C - Cheers :-)

Comment: A function can return a value of any type that you can define for a variable. So you could return a struct if you wanted to. I have actually used returning a struct so that I could return multiple values from the function approximating what is possible with some scripting languages or Go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning a `char *`, not a `char`.  Your code seems to actually require `name_the_file` to return a `char *`, so change the prototype to:

```
char *name_the_file(char *fileName)
```